# how to execute python code in ROS

Tags: python, navigation, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a python file contain the code for the robot patrol around, however, I am not sure how to run the file. I created a package name patrol inside Navigation folder using command:

```
catkin_create_pkg patrol rospy move_base_msgs.msg
chmod +x patrolling.py
rosrun patrol patrolling.py
```

The error said: cannot find the package. I am still new to ROS, so I would like to ask how do I compiled and run the code that I wrote and possibly to launch it with the rviz ?
Thank you,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269380/how-to-execute-python-code-in-ros/) by [kimnguyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/31650/kimnguyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Also, don't forget to source setup.sh !

---

Originally posted by [skander_hannachi](https://answers.ros.org/users/31640/skander_hannachi/) with karma: 26 on 2017-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1